# python loop function to loop another function over a list

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I have a function called `add_ten`. I want to loop this function over a list.
I want to create a `looper` function and pass the `list` and the `add_ten` function to loop over as input

```
def add_ten(x):
    y = x+10
    print 'value of x is ' + str(x)
    print 'value of y is ' + str(y)

def looper(list,func):
    for i in list:
        return func(i)
```

I call the looper function

```
looper([1,2],add_ten())
```

I get this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-6510e446c709> in <module>()
----> 1 looper([1,2],add_ten())

TypeError: add_ten() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

How do I create the looper function properly so that it takes the right arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to understand the question, I arrive at the following working code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function


def add_ten(x):
    print('value of x is %s\nvalue of y is %s' % (str(x), str(x + 10)))


def looper(list, func):
    for i in list:
        func(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    looper([1, 2], add_ten)
```

Output is on my machine:

```
value of x is 1
value of y is 11
value of x is 2
value of y is 12
```

Hope this helps in learning Python ;-)

Note in the implementation of `looper`you for sure do not want to return early in the first iteration, as then only the first list element is processed with a result. Here above I just **call** it and the side effect of the print or whatever is defined in `add_ten` "happens" ...

Answer (score 1):

> `TypeError: add_ten() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

You are getting this error because you are calling the function `add_ten()` without an argument.

---

> I want to create a `looper` function and pass the `list` and the `add_ten` function to loop over as input.

So just pass the function itself in the `looper` function without executing it, like following:

```
looper([1,2], add_ten)
```

And, then call the function within the for loop with the `i` value:

```
def looper(list, func):
    for i in list:
        return func(i)   # <--- notice the parentheses instead of square brackets.
```

Though, I am not sure about the purpose of `return func(i)` since it is not returning anything. So, if you just need to print in the `add_ten` function, you can remove the `return` from this:

```
def looper(list, func):
    for i in list:
        func(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at the error you get: "add_ten() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)".
This is because in `return func[i]` you should do: `return func(i)` (note different brackets).
Otherwise the argument to the call to `funct()` is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont call the function when it's an argument

`looper([1,2], add_ten)`

2. Use parentheses instead of squaree brackets when calling `func(i)`.

Otherwise,your code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

With looper([1,2],add_ten()) your're passing the result of the function-call rather than the function itself.

The fixed version looks like this:

```
def add_ten(x):
    y = x+10
    print 'value of x is ' + str(x)
    print 'value of y is ' + str(y)

def looper(list,func):
    for i in list:
        return func(i)

looper([1,2],add_ten)
```

Also be aware that your add_ten function always returns None and doesn't have any effect but printing the original and the incremented value. A compact way of actually returning an amended list could look like this:

```
def add_ten(x):
    return x + 10

def looper(list,func):
    return [ func(i) for i in list ]

result = looper([1,2],add_ten)
print result
```